# Django Choicefield with required=True and no exception on blank choice

Tags: django, forms, choicefield

***I guess my problem is clear from the title.***

Basically i have a form with dynamic choice fields. And i create a blank option for the select field.

```
 choices = [('', '----------')]
```

Problem is if i submit blank option, form validates. I have django 1.5 installed, so even if in earlier version something like this worked, and validation exception was thrown, now it is not.

***So the big question is , how and where should i validate something like this ?***

I tried to ovveride Choicefield and it's validate method, but i still get the same result:

```
class DynamicChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):
    # The only thing we need to override here is the validate function.
    def validate(self, value):
        if self.required and not value:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])
```

Andy ideas guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES , this is very clear for me. but what you get when you change the required =False . or try to use django force_insert =True  in the model, i never used it , but try it.

Comment: I am kind of at loss right. It so happened i initialized form in one view, but when form was submitted i redirected it to another view where populated it with request.POST. Somehow that plays a role, because now when i moved everything in one view , validation works as expected.